# Pandas: Convert columns of lists into a single list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of lists that looks similar to the one below (fig a). There is a single key column followed by **n** columns containing lists. **My goal is that for each row, I will combine the lists from each column (excluding the key) into a single list in the new column, `combined`**. An example of my desired result is below in figure B.

I've tried some methods with iteritems(), but these dataframes have the potential to be hundreds of thousands to millions of rows long which made it incredibly slow. So I am trying to avoid solutions that use that.

I'd like to use something like the list comprehension seen in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists), but I haven't been able to get it working with pandas.

```
# example data
data = {'key': ['1_1', '1_2', '1_3'],
        'valueA': [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]],
        'valueB': [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]],
        'valueN': [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]]}
dataSet = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Figure A

[image]

Figure B

[image]

Edit: I really appreciate all the answers I have gotten so far! I'm currently going through and timing each on my full size dataset so I can figure out which one will work best this this case. I'll update with my result shortly!

Edit 2: I tested the main solutions provided here on a few of my larger datasets and their average times are below.

```
# Lambda/Apply a nested list comprehension
shakiba.mrd: 1.12 s

# Sum columns
jfaccioni: 2.21 s

# Nested list comprehension with iterrows
mozway: 0.95 s

# Adding column lists together
politinsa: 3.50 s
```

Thanks again to everyone for their contributions!

Comment: When working with lists in pandas you don't have a choice but to loop (explicitly or implicitly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension:

```
dataSet['combined'] = [[e for l in x for e in l]
                       for _,x in dataSet.filter(like='value').iterrows()]
```

Output:

```
   key                    valueA                    valueB                    valueN                                                                  combined
0  1_1        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]                    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
1  1_2     [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]     [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]     [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]           [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
2  1_3  [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]  [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]  [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]  [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
```

Timing comparison with repeated addition (100 rows, 100 columns, 1000 items per list):

```
# repeated addition of the lists
8.66 s ± 309 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# nested list comprehension
729 ms ± 285 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can add lists in python

```py
df['combined'] = df['valueA'] + df['valueB'] + df['valueN']
```

Or for multiple columns:

```py
df['combined'] = [[] for _ in range(len(df))]
for letter in ['A', 'B', 'C', ...., 'N']:
    df['combined'] += df[f'value{letter}']
```

Comment: This might look like a nice solution but repeatedly adding list has a quadratic complexity and thus should really be avoided

Comment: @mozway yes but my answer isn't the problem here, it's their question. If he wants to concatenate several lists (it was their question), they can use my solution. The real problem is why does they have to concatenate lists in the first place and is this step time critical.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply select the columns that contain the lists, then sum the columns with `.sum(axis=1)`.

It works like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'key': ['1_1', '1_2', '1_3'],
    'valueA': [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]],
    'valueB': [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]],
    'valueN': [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]],
}
dataSet = pd.DataFrame(data)

columns_to_combine = ['valueA', 'valueB', 'valueN']

dataSet['combined'] = dataSet[columns_to_combine].sum(axis=1)
dataSet.drop(columns=columns_to_combine, inplace=True) # remove the old columns

print(dataSet)

# output:
#    key                                                                  combined
# 0  1_1                    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
# 1  1_2           [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
# 2  1_3  [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
```

Comment: `sum` on lists has a quadratic complexity as it builds again a new list for each added item.

Answer (score 1):

First you should merge these columns into one new column:

```
merge_columns = list(dataSet.columns)
merge_columns.remove("key")
dataSet["combined"] = dataSet[merge_columns].values.tolist()
```

Then you should make a list from list of lists in each row:

```
dataSet["combined"] = dataSet["combined"].apply(lambda x: [item for sublist in x for item in sublist])
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is the easiest way to reach your goal.**

> ```
> dataSet['Lists'] = dataSet['valueA'] + dataSet['valueB'] + dataSet['valueN']
> dataSet.drop(columns=['valueA','valueB',"valueN"],inplace=True)
> print(dataSet)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
dataSet.set_index('key').apply(lambda ss:np.array(ss.tolist()).flatten(),axis=1)
```

## output:

```
#    key                                                                  combined
# 0  1_1                    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
# 1  1_2           [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
# 2  1_3  [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
```